# копия canvas-a в canvas-е

Tags: c#, wpf

Как сделать копию canvas-a в canvas-е только отдалённую? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно по-всякому. Например так:

```
<Window x:Class="VisualBrushTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Visual Brush test" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Name="Original" Background="LemonChiffon" Margin="30">
            <TextBlock Text="London is the capital of Great Britain" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       FontFamily="Monotype Corsiva" FontSize="24"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1"
              Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Original}"
              Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Original}">
            <Grid.Background>
                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Original}"/>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Value, ElementName=ScaleSlider}"
                                ScaleY="{Binding Value, ElementName=ScaleSlider}"/>
            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
        </Grid>

        <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="1" Value="0.25" Name="ScaleSlider"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Получается что-то такое:

[image: London]